# Stripe Subscription issue in django?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Having issues getting the Stripe subscription working in my Django application. right now I have this as my view:

```
def subscribe(request):

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        description = 'This is the test customer',
        )

    if request.method=='POST':
        stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer= customer.id,
            items = [{"Basic Plan": "prod_HHU1r1fphhhqLt"}]
            )
        return render(request, 'landing/charge.html')
```

Im getting the error:

```
Request req_69L7P1bcp8iZ1e: Received unknown parameter: items[0][Basic Plan]
```

which is confusing because the info is coming straight from my stripe plan so I know it exists

(edit) here is the traceback if it helps:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/web1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/web1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/web1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/swapp/landing/views.py", line 79, in subscribe
    stripe.Subscription.create(
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/web1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 22, in create
    response, api_key = requestor.request("post", url, params, headers)
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/web1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 122, in request
    resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/web1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 373, in interpret_response
    self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders)
  File "/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/python/Environments/web1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 152, in handle_error_response
    raise err

Exception Type: InvalidRequestError at /subscribe/
Exception Value: Request req_69L7P1bcp8iZ1e: Received unknown parameter: items[0][Basic Plan]```


Im pretty postitive its something simple but Im pretty new to django and cant seem to get it figured out. Thank you!
````

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the wrong parameter.
the creation of the subscription takes a list of dictionaries having the ID of the plan with key 'plan'. There is no parameter named 'Basic Plan'. So to avoid the error please make following changes:

```
def subscribe(request):

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        description = 'This is the test customer',
        )

    if request.method=='POST':
        stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer= customer.id,
            items = [{"plan": "prod_HHU1r1fphhhqLt"}]
            )
        return render(request, 'landing/charge.html')
```

Noice the Key 'Basic Plan' is changed to 'plan' in the items parameter.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: great thanks, I thought that that was supposed to be the name of whatever plan that I am trying to use. switched it and all is good, thank you!